# Load Zend Optimizer for php 5.3

Tags: php, zend-optimizer

I follow their guide http://kb.zend.com/index.php?View=entry&EntryID=424 to enable  Zend Optimizer in my php.ini and it does not work properly.

in php.ini i have

```
zend_extension_ts = "ZendLoader.dll"
```

php.ini is loaded correctly, before i had a problem like `Failed loading ZendLoader.dll` but later i found that i need to use `zend_extension_ts` instead of `zend_extension` because my php is a TS version.

And now PHP doesn't show any errors, but in phpinfo() or PHP -m, i don't see any zend extensions loaded. 
Anyone suggestions on how i could make this to work ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Zend Optimizer doesn't exist for PHP 5.3.

The product was renamed ZendGuard when it was released for PHP 5.3. However, ZendGuard cannot load files that were encoded for Zend Optimizer, and vice versa -- they're effectively two separate products. If you've got an application that was encoded for Zend Optimizer, you're stuck on PHP 5.2.

Comment: This is one reason why I'd strongly advise webmasters to **avoid encoded applications** unless you have an ongoing support relationship with the author. Encoders (and encoded files) have a way of breaking with PHP updates, and you're left with something that's intentionally unfixable.

Comment: a part of application is delivered encoded, and i will downgrade to PHP5.2, @duskwuff thank you.

Comment: finally i was able to decode the encoded files here http://www.showmycode.com/ :))